# Server Application Error PHP

Tags: php, fastcgi

I have installed PHP
By using: FastCGI
System specs:
Windows XP servicepack 3
C++ 2012 redistributable runtime

when i am opening my PHP document trough:
jmnet.servegame.com/test.php

i get this error:
Server Application Error
The server has encountered an error while loading an application during the processing of your request. Please refer to the event log for more detail information. Please contact the server administrator for assistance.

php version: 5.6.10 NON-Thread-Safe
FastCGI version: 1.5
IIS Version: 1.5

```
Service cannot be started. System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The specified executable is not a valid Win32 application.
    at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo) at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
    at winsw.WrapperService.StartProcess(Process processToStart, String arguments, String executable)
    at winsw.WrapperService.OnStart(String[] _)
    at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.ServiceQueuedMainCallback(Object state)

For more information, see Help and Support Center at go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
```

Comment: Did you _refer to the event log for more detail information_?

Comment: I cand find the file :(
i did checkout the inifile of PHP and FastCGI i dont know where errors get stored

Comment: You'll probably need to look in the Windows Event logs: Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Event Viewer

Comment: Found it:
Service cannot be started. System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The specified executable is not a valid Win32 application.
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at winsw.WrapperService.StartProcess(Process processToStart, String arguments, String executable)
   at winsw.WrapperService.OnStart(String[] _)
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.ServiceQueuedMainCallback(Object state)

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

Comment: I did download PHP from: http://windows.php.net/download#php-5.6
FastCGI from: iis.com/Downloads/FastCGI

Comment: Did you download the x86 or x64 version? It looks like you need the x86 version (32 bit).

Comment: @GregBurghardt Reinstalled now used: Nontreadsafe php 5.6.10 (x86) what didnt make any difference (http://jmnet.servegame.com/test.php)

Comment: @Greg I did download PHP x86 and FastCGI x86 doesnt work